# Accessing $t in Nuxt Vuex States

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-i18n

I want to access `nuxt-i18n` $t() for multi lang texts in `vuex` state but we do not have access this in `vuex` store

Comment: This is quite helpful IMO: https://github.com/nuxt-community/i18n-module/issues/1386

Comment: It is necessary to have vuex access to use $t. Without the vuex access the translations are not accessible for i18n.